# The probability that the drawn card are face card of of same suits.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Three cards are drawn successively,without replacement from the pack of 52 cards.Then the probability that the drawn card are face card of same suits , is ?

My approach :
Probability of select one suit among 4 is 1/4.

Among each suits, there are 3 face card so the probability of face cards among each suits is (3/13)*(2/12)*(1/11).

So Required probability is 1/4 * (3/13)*(2/11)*(1/11).

Is the above approach correct?

Please help me.

Comment: How many ways are there to draw 3 cards from a deck of 52? How many suits are there? For each suit, how many ways are there to draw 3 cards from them? Please try to show some of your effort when asking a question.

Comment: I have edited my approach.

Comment: I don't think it is, but try this: find the probability that the first card is a face card. Find the probability that the second card is then a face card of the same suit as the first. Find the probability that the third card is then a face card of the same suit as the first two.  Multiply these probabilities.

Comment: Probability of first card is of face card is (4*3)/52 . probability of second card is face card of same suits as of first card is 2/51. Probability of third card is face card of same suits as the first two cards is 1/50.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (If a "face card" is king, queen, or jack.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one thing to note is that the question indicates **no replacement** this is usually a good hint for you to think about the hypergeometric distribution as that is the only probability distribution with no replacement.

In general, the distribution takes the following form:

$\frac{{K \choose k} {N-K \choose n-k}}{N \choose n} $

Where:

$N$ is the population size,
$K$ is the number of success states in the population,
$n$ is the number of draws (i.e. quantity drawn in each trial),
$k$ is the number of observed successes

The probability of drawing $3$ face cards of the same suit is then the following:

$\frac{{4 \choose 3} {48 \choose 0}}{52 \choose 3} =\frac{{4 \choose 3} }{52 \choose 3}$

Note that this counts the ace as a face card, if you don't want to count it that would be

$\frac{{3 \choose 3} {48 \choose 0}}{52 \choose 3} =\frac{{3 \choose 3} }{52 \choose 3}$

Then this should be multiplied by $4$ since that is the probability of drawing all $4$ face cards from one specific suit (so for example that is the probability of drawing all heart face cards, we multiply by $4$ to take into account ace, spades, and I forgot what the last suit is called.

so our final answer would be $4 \cdot \frac{{4 \choose 3} }{52 \choose 3}$ if we count the ace and $4 \cdot \frac{{3 \choose 3} }{52 \choose 3}$

Note that this isn't the only way to do it, the other way would be using multiplication rule, we can do the following (here I am not counting ace as a face card:

$\frac{3}{52}\cdot \frac{2}{51}\cdot\frac{1}{50}$ that is, probability of getting the first face card from a specific deck multiplied by the probability of getting the second face card from the same deck multiplied by the probability of getting the third face card from the same deck and then multiply the final answer by $4$ again (due to the same explanation) which would give the same result, note that since you are drawing these cards with no replacement the denominator is decreasing.

Comment: Are you counting an ace as a "face" card?

Comment: yes I am, sometimes it is counted and others no so this kinda confuses, I will leave a note for that

Comment: The thing about ace is sometimes in playing decks it is just marked as number one, sometimes it is an ace, I found this to differ between a book author and another